# My Ajax/Jquery for a select is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in my MVC application and I'm struggling with it because I don't know much Jquery.

The intention is to send the select value to a controller, but it's not working.

HELP.
tks in advance

```
<div class="Left Width50Perc" style="display: inline">
    <select id="searchForBondsSelect" class="selectedValue">
        <option value="Bonds">Bonds</option>
        <option value="Stocks">Stocks</option>
        <option value="Funds">Funds</option>
        <option value="ETFS">ETFs</option>
    </select>
 </div>

<script>
    $(".selectedValue").select(
        {
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(".selectedValue").val(ui.select.val);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/searchtool/st/GetProductType",
                    data: { productType: ui.select.val },
                    async: true,
                    type: "POST",

                })
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Not working means? Ajax call is not fired? Or fired with wrong value of select? Try using `$(this).val()` instead of `ui.select.val`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

`$(".selectedValue").change(function() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "/searchtool/st/GetProductType",
         data: { productType: $(this).val() },
         async: true,
         type: "POST",
     })
});`

Hope that works.

Comment: Men, you're a life saver. Thanks a million.

Comment: Glad that I could help :) @ruimartins

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first make a function:

```
Function PostData()
{
var productType=$('#dropDownId :selected').text();
 $.ajax({
                    url: "/searchtool/st/GetProductType",
                    data: { productType: productType},
                    async: true,
                    type: "POST",

                })
}
```